# Asignar valores con forEach

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ejercicio del cual me pide crear un array vacio de 50 posiciones que lo he creado de la siguiente forma:
`arrayVacio = new Array(50);`
Y ahora lo siguiente que me pide es que asigne valores aleatorios entre 10 y 40 con un foreach. He intentado hacer:

```js
arrayVacio = new Array(50);
arrayVacio.forEach (ejercicio10);
function ejercicio10(){
  for (var x=10; x<40; x++){arrayVacio.push}
}
```

Pero no me funciona correctamente y creo que se podría hacer de una forma más simplificada pero la verdad no se de que forma hacerlo.

Comment: Soy nueva por aqui, si creen que deba cambiar la pregunta para que esté mejor formulada, agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Te fijaste en la documentación la sintaxis de `forEach`? Además, esos no son valores aleatorios entre 10 y 40, sino valores únicos desde 10 hasta 39...

Comment: Y ademas, for y foreach no son los mismos.

Comment: Debe ser foreach o for? o cualquiera?

Comment: Debe ser forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El constructor `new Array(N)` crea un array, **pero no es iterable**, por ello no va a funcionar `.forEach` ni `.map` por ejemplo. Para que sea iterable se puede usar la sintaxis de destructuring `[...Array(50)]`, ahí si es iterable y se puede por ejemplo usar `.map`:

```js
const min = 10;
const max = 40;
const res = [...Array(50)].map(e=>Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));

console.log(res);
```

Si si o si quieres usar el constructor y `forEach` podrías hacer algo (bastante confuso y poco recomendable) asi:

```js
const min = 10;
const max = 40;
const arrayVacio = new Array(50);
[...arrayVacio].forEach((e,i)=>arrayVacio[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));


console.log(arrayVacio);
```

Comment: Hola emeeus, tu respuesta me vendría muy bien, pero debo hacerlo si o si con forEach, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

no es aconsejable usar new en js, aunque si asi te lo requieren esta bien. Una forma de hacerlo podria ser esta:

```
let arrayVacio = [];
//el ciclo for va metiendo en cada posicion del array (i) un numero aleatorio de 0 a 50, se consigue con funciones que vienen en la libreria Math estandar de JS
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      arrayVacio[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * (50));
    }
//este for es solo para mostrar los resultados por consola
    for(i=0; i < arrayVacio.length; i++){
      console.log(arrayVacio[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una breve explicación:

Crear un array no es asignarle valores, cuando creas array con valor `new array(50)` solo le estas diciendo la cantidad de elementos que puede contener ese array mas no valores.

Ejemplo con FOR

```js
//Creo el Array
arrayVacio = [];

//Asigno del 0 al 49 vacios (50 En total)
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arrayVacio.push([]);
}

//Por Último Asigno un "1" del 10 al 40 (Puedes colocar cualquier cosa, el 1 es ejemplo)
for (var i = 10; i < 41; i++) {
    arrayVacio[i]="1";
}

console.log(arrayVacio);
```

Si deseas Hacerlo con ForEach

```js
//Creo el Array
arrayVacio = [];

//Asigno del 0 al 49 vacios (50 En total)
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    arrayVacio.push([]);
}

//y con ForEach asignas a los que necesitas igual

arrayVacio.forEach( function(valor, indice, array) {
    if(indice>9 && indice<41)
    {
        arrayVacio[indice]=1;
    }
});

console.log(arrayVacio);
```

Recuerda crear Array y luego Asignarle Valores

Comment: Hola Josue, intento hacer lo del forEach, pero en el array no me inserta los valores aleatorios.

Comment: Puedes colocar tu codigo aqui https://jsfiddle.net/ para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

```
Con forEach

    arrayVacio1 =Array.apply(null, Array(50));
     // por ejemplo Array.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]); // => [1, 2, 3]
    
     function llenoArray1(){
           for(var i = 0; i < arrayVacio1.length; i++){
     
          arrayVacio1.forEach(
            (item,i,self)=>self[i]=Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 10+ 1) +10)); 
          }
          
        }


           // con estos resultados podes ver el problema
          vacio= new Array(50)
 vacioApply=Array.apply(null, Array(50))
```

> ```
>              // empty items no se puede hacer lo que queres usar foreach
> ```
>
> //muestra new Array(50) [ <50 empty items> ]

console.log('new Array(50)',vacio);

> ```
>              // de esta forma si  // muestra vacioApply [undefined..... undefined]
> ```

```
                console.log('vacioApply',vacioApply)

         llenoArray1()
           //imprime resultado
          console.log('Resultado',arrayVacio1)
/*
Resultado [
  23, 14, 22, 10, 35, 36, 30, 21, 38, 29, 33,
  29, 36, 10, 29, 22, 16, 31, 28, 36, 29, 17,
  31, 31, 38, 29, 30, 22, 32, 32, 23, 10, 27,
  23, 31, 14, 15, 14, 11, 14, 14, 36, 23, 28,
  16, 33, 37, 39, 30, 30
]
*/

Sin usar operador Spread(propagacion) ni map() ni forEach() solo con push


    var arrayVacio = new Array();
    
    // te piden  50 posiciones
    function ejercicio10(){
    
      for (var x=1; x<51; x++){console.log(x),llenoArray(x)}
    }
    
        // lleno las 50 posiciones
        function llenoArray(x){
          y=Math.floor(Math.random() * (40 - 10+ 1) +10)
          arrayVacio.push(y);  
        }
        
        //llamo a la funcion
           ejercicio10()
           //imprime resultado
          console.log('Resultado',arrayVacio)

        /*
        Resultado: [
      31, 39, 13, 13, 36, 23, 22, 16, 40, 11, 11,
      29, 39, 12, 29, 24, 23, 12, 11, 10, 40, 39,
      35, 32, 38, 37, 18, 27, 18, 29, 34, 39, 20,
      40, 21, 14, 18, 15, 31, 39, 17, 28, 34, 11,
      12, 34, 39, 33, 34, 14
    ]
        
        
        */
```

Comment: Hola nstdan, veo muy correcto tu respuesta pero no me sirve...necesitaría usar si o si el forEach, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: agrege mi solucion con forEach

Comment: tampoco te sirve?